# Typescript optional generic property

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, typescript-generics

I have this type where my `value` property is "optional" (if `T` is not `undefined`)

```
type AsyncState<T = undefined> = {
    value?: T;
    loading: boolean;
    error: { reason: string } | null;
}
```

Now I need to somehow create new object that depends on `AsyncState` parameter - add `value` property if `T` is not `undefined` and don't if `T` is undefined. (this is just dummy example of more complicated logic, but since types are problem, it should be enough)

```
function asyncGet<T>(initialState: AsyncState<T>) {
    return typeof initialState.value !== 'undefined' 
        ? (s: AsyncState<T>) => ({ ...initialState })
        : (s: AsyncState) => ({ loading: initialState.loading, error: initialState.error });
}


const first: AsyncState<string> = {
    loading: true,
    error: null,
    value: ""
}

const second: AsyncState<string> = {
    loading: true,
    error: null,
    value: ""
}

const creator = asyncGet(first);

/* 
Argument of type 'AsyncState<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AsyncState<string> & AsyncState<undefined>'.
  Type 'AsyncState<string>' is not assignable to type 'AsyncState<undefined>'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
*/
creator(second);
```

Here is [typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggziAdgYwMrAIbAgHgCpQC8UArogCYQBmAlohOQHxFQDeAsAFBRQBuGAGxIQA-AC4oeANxceAgPYZydAOYSARvPkCIGRDO5QIAJ2PzjE1lGO648xBLjBjqqAF8oAHyiISAgQZuBlxUZMjANPZQGAgoAOIQwPiMABR0NBGC6FgQEvBIaJjYyQCUbLLWiSTGiFCgkPJUUOmZAtnYAHT8QtAAhITEAERklLT05IMVPCJQKXB5sYU5pUTMKVYdmy00WUXQbiVTUBJzCwXtEGWEaxyGPPdQCkqqEtu7OR1PyogqADRHDxMZgszUQGR2bT2HSB5gB7hKgS4XGQ9icUFoxicZxQFxwThcP2YxFuckU3zUdWMwn+hhhIN8-hpPG6wgkg14AEZJpwgkjOCjEGi4BABeRsUtivjVETyoYvi9KdSKnSJAyBEy+IJWVB2QAmbm8zjI1HAKDIGxYcwsGIFBLAFIYpwIvkAegAVFAjjBjCoSABbCCIU2NOrgaAAcnyOL2eOc0vDzTgPnkppicBoKkQGHUOjq8igYAwxgwAewxigIfqEajEtwUsJUAAZLBFriRtQ6AxGOGOnC8GGoJHWzH6ypu4nk6m4OnM9nc8B81XBzW2xQO+Nu727g9JAPw6OEzQk4gU9FpxmsznoAvQ5BB+2xgwe0c3S7kRaF8Y5iL7ORnZwgA).

Comment: Why are you using a conditional type instead of `type AsyncState<T> = {loading: boolean; error: {reason: string} | null; value?: T | null}`?  The difference seems small enough and it would have to be easier to deal with...

Comment: @jcalz I had similar setup, but then in my redux store I'd always have that value: null although I don't even need it there (basically I just need to track error and loading for specific properties, e.g. login action)

Comment: If `value` is optional as in `{value?: T | null}` then you don't need `value: null`, right?  It would just be left out.  I could possibly take as given that you need to use the relatively clunky conditional type, but I'd like to see a [mcve] here with actual use cases.  As it stands I don't how to proceed (what's `combineReducers()`?  This question is not tagged `redux` and if you need redux expertise then it probably should be... if it's not about redux then make some example use cases without being dependent on it).  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Please take a look at edited solution (one using value?: T), and also without any redux references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this by making the returned function that needs to infer the *actual* type of `T` generic.

```
function asyncGet<T>(initialState: AsyncState<T>) {
  return typeof initialState.value !== "undefined"
    ? (s: AsyncState<T>) => ({ ...initialState })
    : <U>(s: AsyncState<U>) => ({
        loading: initialState.loading,
        error: initialState.error
      });
}
```

That said, this will get you in trouble if you ever try to override TypeScript's inference by calling it like this: `asyncGet<string>({ loading: true, error: null })`

A better solution is to use a conditional type to specify that the function conditionally uses the inferred value of the call to the returned function.

```
function asyncGet<T>(initialState: AsyncState<T>): 
  <U>(s: AsyncState<[T] extends [undefined] ? U : T>) => 
    AsyncState<[T] extends [undefined] ? U : T> {

  return typeof initialState.value !== "undefined"
    ? (s) => ({ ...initialState })
    : (s) => ({
        loading: initialState.loading,
        error: initialState.error
      });
}
```